# MathJax in div incorrect height

Tags: javascript, html, css, height, mathjax

I am trying to figure out why MathJax render block gives me the wrong height for the div. The code is

```
<div class="text-field" id='inner-text'>\(\sqrt{b^{a}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}}\)</div>
```

with CSS

```
.text-field {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 15em;
}
```

When the following JS snippet is run

```
  MathJax.typeset();
  let text = document.getElementById("inner-text");
  console.log(text.clientHeight,
              text.offsetHeight,
              text.getBoundingClientRect().height,
              window.getComputedStyle(text).getPropertyValue('height'));
```

The console gives

```
41 41 41.25 "41.25px"
```

However, in inspect elements:

[image]

The actual height does not agree with any of height options accessible via JS. What is going on and how should can a get an accurate height value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it takes MathJax time to create the visualization. The idea of the solution I made is to give time to MathJax and when it is ready then we take the size of the element.

I made two versions of the code. Both work correctly in Firefox, Chrome, Edge... etc.

**Option 1:**

The script waits for MathJax to load then gives it another 100ms to complete and then takes the size of the `inner-text`

```js
var checkEx = setInterval(function () {
    let wrap = document.getElementById("inner-text");
    var text = wrap.getElementsByClassName('MathJax')[0];
    if (text) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(wrap.getBoundingClientRect().height, wrap.getBoundingClientRect().width);
        }, 100);
        clearInterval(checkEx);
    }
}, 100);
```

```css
.text-field {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 15em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>


<div class="text-field" id='inner-text'>\(\sqrt{b^{a}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}}\)</div>
```

---

**Option 2**

The script waits for MathJax to load then begins to take the size of the element. When the size stops changing... return the size of the `inner-text`

```js
var elhg;
var elwg;

var checkEx = setInterval(function () {
    let wrap = document.getElementById("inner-text");
    var text = wrap.getElementsByClassName('MathJax')[0];
    if (text) {

        elHeight = wrap.getBoundingClientRect().height;
        elWidth = wrap.getBoundingClientRect().width;

        if (elhg === elHeight && elwg === elWidth) {
            console.log(elHeight, elWidth);
            clearInterval(checkEx);
        }

        elhg = elHeight;
        elwg = elWidth;
    }
}, 100);
```

```css
.text-field {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 15em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>

<div class="text-field" id='inner-text'>\(\sqrt{b^{a}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}}\)</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed solutions! I thought MathJax.typeset() being synchronous means that it should produce the correct dimensions when finishes; turns out I was wrong. Another question: if I have a bunch of these MathJax-containing divs (potentially a lot of them, so would be hard to specify a timeout value to wait for rendering finish), and I want to wait till all of them have the right dimensions before taking measurements, what is the more efficient way to do so?

Comment: I will try to make it work for more "MathJax" items ... :)

Comment: In fact, I found a solution: I can check dimensions on window.onload, and that should give me all the correctly rendered sizes. Again, thanks a lot for your help!